# Boost Serialization multiple objects

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am serializing a class with boost using binary.  I'm using ios::append in order to keep appending multiple objects to this file.  How do I go about retrieving all of the objects that are stored?

Here is my test class which tries a multiple serialize and retrieve them.  I've comment the failure point where I don't get correct data.

```
using namespace std;
 class Data {
 public:
double get_latitude() const {
    return _latitude;
}

double get_longitude() const {
    return _longitude;
}

void set_latitude(double _latitude) {
    this->_latitude = _latitude;
}

void set_longitude(double _longitude) {
    this->_longitude = _longitude;
}
private:
double _latitude;
double _longitude;
friend class boost::serialization::access;
// When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
// & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
// is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & _latitude;
    ar & _longitude;
}
};

class DataTest: public CppUnit::TestFixture {
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( DataTest);
CPPUNIT_TEST(testMultipleSaveData);
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:

void testMultipleSaveData() {
    Data data;
    data.set_latitude(1.0);
    data.set_longitude(2.0);
    saveData(data);
    Data secondData;
    secondData.set_latitude(5.0);
    secondData.set_longitude(6.0);
    saveData(secondData);
    Data returnData;
    Data return2Data;
    {
        // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("data.dat", ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> returnData;
        ia >> return2Data;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(data.get_latitude(), returnData.get_latitude());
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(data.get_longitude(), returnData.get_longitude());
    //Failure on next line
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(secondData.get_latitude(), return2Data.get_latitude());
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(secondData.get_longitude(), return2Data.get_longitude());
}

void saveData(Data data) {
    std::ofstream ofs("data.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << data;
}

 };
 CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION( DataTest);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decided to add another answer to avoid complete mess.

Your problem is that you serialize to separate instances of `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`. **Boost Archive** stores some internal info at the beginning of the file (I won't call it a header because **Boost Serialization** has separate header to store version number), and you receive two copies of this info, at the beginning of the file and between your Data serializations.

**Boost Archive** wasn't designed for such usage. Even specifying `boost::archive::no_header` like in:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs, boost::archive::no_header);
```

doesn't help, because this option configures another header, that contains version number. You need to serialize to the same instance of **Boost Archive**.

Comment: So is there an easy way to change it to make it work or do you think Boost Serialization is not the right choice for my requirement?

Comment: As I wrote, you need to serialize to the same instance of Boost Archive. Open it -> serialize **all** objects -> close it.

Comment: can downvoter explain the reason? downvoting accepted answers 6 days later? is it just some sort of vendetta?

Answer (score 3):

1) if the number of objects stored is constant - load all of them in the same order you stored them:

storing:

```
std::ofstream ofs(FILENAME, ios::app);
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << data1 << data2 << ... << data_n;
```

loading:

```
std::ifstream ifs(FILENAME);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
ia >> data1 >> data2 >> ... >> data_n;
```

2) if the number of objects stored can vary - serialize the number:

storing:

```
std::ofstream ofs(FILENAME, ios::app);
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << number_of_objects;
for (size_t i = 0; i != number_of_objects; ++i)
    oa << data[i];
```

loading:

```
std::ifstream ifs(FILENAME);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
size_t number_of_objects;
ia >> number_of_objects;
// allocate number_of_objects objects
for (size_t i = 0; i != number_of_objects; ++i)
    ia >> data[i];
```

[EDIT] taking into account your edited question:
first of all, you use `binary_archive` with text-mode files! you need to open the file (for both reading and writing) with std::ios::binary flag. this is a bug and can be a reason of your problem ("can be" because we don't see your exact serialization implementation).

I cannot compile your code because it's incomplete. try to implement simple class with serialization and store/load 2 objects on this simple example to easily find what wrong with more complicated cases

[EDIT2] did you take `binary_archive` from **Boost.Serialization** examples? if so be aware it's not portable, I don't know if this matters for you

Comment: That does work if I have all the objects to save at once.  I'll be serializing a new object every second.  So it creates a new line, and it doesn't work when loading.  It just loads the first one.  Any ideas?

Comment: no matter how often or how many objects you serialize. pls provide a simplified but complete example how you do this so we'll point exactly what's wrong

Comment: ok, i've added some more information to my original post.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've updated the code sample with a complete sample in a test class.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read more than one, then tell it to load more than one.  Serialization only knows to load multiple objects when you've told it to either explicitly or by serializing a container of objects.